# Retrofit Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

Hi guys I am fairly new to retrofit library from Sqareup. I have created a web service using Laravel framework. When I give a wrong or malformed phone number it should give me a proper error as json.
I am trying to parse this JSON response:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "mobile_number": [
            "The mobile number format is invalid.",
            "The mobile number must be 11 digits."
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my model class:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;


public class LoginResult {
    @SerializedName("mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String action;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("errors")
    private Errors errors;

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }


    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }


    public Errors getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }


    public static class Errors {
        @SerializedName("mobile_number")
        @Expose
        private List<String> mobileNumber = null;

        public List<String> getMobileNumber() {
            return mobileNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Login {
    @SerializedName("mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public Login(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }
}
```

My interface:

```
import ir.husoft.kasbokar.models.Login;
import ir.husoft.kasbokar.models.LoginResult;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface ApiInterface {
    @POST("api/auth/login")
    Call<LoginResult> login(@Body Login login);
}
```

Here is ApiClient:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

my success method:

```
ApiInterface api = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
String mobileNumber = etMobileNumber.getText().toString();
            Login login = new Login(mobileNumber);
            Call<LoginResult> verification = api.login(login);
            verification.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginResult> call, Response<LoginResult> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Action is: " + response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error code: " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginResult> call, Throwable throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, throwable.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

When I use it on my success method it throws the error

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1

What is wrong here?

Comment: Your server is not returning JSON for your request, apparently. Add [the logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) to your OkHttp/Retrofit setup for debug builds, then examine Logcat to see what the server is returning. Or, use tools like Charles Proxy to examine what the server is returning. Or, perhaps you can find out what the server is returning through some work on the server itself.

Comment: I am using postman to test the api. It works perfect with it. Also when I give a correct mobile number it works with no problem. only when I give a wrong number it gives me error. It seems retrofit have a problem with this part

Comment: where did you use Gson?

Comment: @Mr.AF I have edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I forgot to set the Headers for the request. The ApiInterface must be look like this:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    @POST("api/auth/login")
    Call<LoginResult> login(@Body Login login);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove `private String mobileNumber` from `LoginResult` also `mobileNumber` is a array or a List of String.

Comment: The problem is in my web service. when I create the exact same JSON manually it works like a charm. But when I use the web service it gives me that error. I am confused because both JSON responses are the same.

Comment: The `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1` means that your model is not matching your response. That's where you issue is.

Comment: In both JSON files (One which I have created manually and another that web service gives me) I receive 422 response code. According to above code when I use the manually created the JSON file, it prints out the error code "422". But when usig actual web service it throws an exception. Both response are OK when using Postman

Comment: Did you add a `user-agent` or a token in Postman ? Also can you post both JSON  response just to be sure it's the same and you didn't miss anything.
I've just noticed but your `BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";` is wrong. If you emulate and call localhost it'll be localhost of your phone not your computer. You should put your computer-IP instead.

Comment: Thanks @Biscuit. I finally found the problem. The IP address is correct because I am using a physical device to test the app. The problem was that I had forgotten to set Accept header. In post man I used this header to receive to correct response

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for registering your data type where GSON is failing to convert in my case it was an Instant data type that was CreatedDate field in my model class.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Instant.class, new JsonDeserializer<Instant>() {
            @Override
            public Instant deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                    throws JsonParseException {
                return Instant.parse(json.getAsString());
            }
        }).create();
        retrofitClient = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Config.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(retroHttpClient)
                .build();
```